# Ubuntu 15.04 looks like 14 with problems

Tags: updates, 15.04, desktop-background

Recently I tried to upgrade from ubuntu `14.04` to `15`. The upgrade completed, but it seems all I got was a black wallpaper.
Software updater says the update diddn't complete, so it recommends I do a partial update. Unfortunately it give me the Error message :

```
Cannot upgrade an upgrade from vivid to Utopic is not supported with this tool
```

Someone help please.

Comment: could you do `sudo apt-get install -f` in a terminal and post errors that come (if any).

Answer (score 1):

The way ubuntu starts up and etc. is changed on 15. You should always use a LTS version of ubuntu if you want to be sure that it runs fine. 14.04 is the latest LTS version. You may look on the change log and see if it has something to do with it.

If it doesn't help start into recovery mode and try executing following lines either in root mode or with prepending `sudo`:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install --fix-missing
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoclean
```

If it does not help, you could reinstall ubuntu.

For that, download the ISO, boot into the Live-CD (you can use an usb flash drive as well) and copy the /home directory of your current installed ubuntu partition to any external place (other partition, external hard drive, ...)

Then just reinstall ubuntu and copy the home directory back. You only need to install all the packages you had and reconfigure them if needed.

Please give some more detail about your actual problem.